# Word document hyperlink

Tags: ms-word, hyperlink

I want to keep a hyperlink in the page which takes me to another page in the same document.I am not sure how to do this.Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Bah! I thought "codument" was a great new word for describing badly written documents.

Comment: Nah, it's a form of syntactic sugar. Or maybe mustard.

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe I'm linking to Yahoo Answers, but it's a good one:

> **[How do you make internal links in Microsoft Word?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080822000441AAaXTv7)**
>
> In general, you can link to a point in the document by setting a bookmark there, then inserting a hyperlink to the bookmark at the jump-from point. To set a bookmark in Word 2002 (XP) and the adjacent versions:
>
> 1. Click exactly where you want the bookmark to be in the text.
> 2. Click the Insert->Bookmark menu item.
> 3. Give the bookmark a name.
> 4. Click Add.
>
> To insert a hyperlink to a bookmark,
>
> 1. Click the Insert->Hyperlink menu item.
> 2. Click the Place In This Document panel.

Comment: BTW, I answered in the spirit of being helpful, but this is not a programming question, so i've also voted to close

Comment: Thank you for your service.